# Could Not Found A Way To Align Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to align different type of codes. For example, if html I need to align it using tags, but did not found any way.

I tried notepad++ plugin "Code alignment" but unable to align.

For Example, From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Is there no software or tool or website to align these with One Click?

Comment: I am sure you are aware, that alignment of your table cells really has no benefit for display purposes and only serves as a visual help for you. Furthermore, it is not recommended to clutter your html with white space.

Comment: So you want software that will auto align the tags for you? Weird question if I may say. Why not just align them yourself? What is your goal or end goal?

Comment: There are plenty of tools that can do this; search for "html beautifier" or "html pretty print" or something. However, be aware that they probably won't prettify it quite like you did in your second picture -- they'll format it according to common HTML conventions.

Comment: All your tags are irrelevant.

Comment: i tried almost EVERYTHING!!!!!!!

Comment: Gawd... I don't know, use tabs? Seems logical.

Comment: Your question was already answered by @oxguy3. There really is no point in aligning the <td> tags unless you drop them all down by one line and then tab them in. alignment of <td> tags is mainly for better reading and no other purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Rick  If there is no such tool available, maybe you should write your own. Your question is tagged javascript and php, so how well versed are you in those languages?

Comment: also i need exact type of alignment in javascript and php to edit code easier

Comment: I'm sure you can instruct notepad++ to add indentation to certain tags. Visit their website, they've a list of plugins in there and there's probably something already in the program. Maybe even a macro.

Comment: I am thinking, your right @Fred-ii- If I were in his position, I would write a simple macro to solve the issue if it were something that would save me time in the long run.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I do remember (at one point in time) going through some of the options and plugins that I have in my installation, however, I can't remember where/what they were. I'm not about to spend time on this; something that the OP should be doing, not us. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- is Mr. Rick trolling you too? lol, or am I the only lucky one?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I'm a big fish alright, like a ***marlin***. Let's see him reel/troll me in. He's gonna have a helluva time and will have to wake up pretty early to even *try* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**1** - Don't Be Lazy.

**2** - Use the `Tab` button.

**3** - When you press the `Tab` button it will move your text to the next available line.

**4** - repeat until your code looks like you want it too.

FURTHERMORE: what you are asking is not the "industry standard" or what ever you want to call it. You would have a lot more luck trying to find a program that will align it like this example below, because this is how the majority does it.

```
<table>
      <tr>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td>      
            <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>        
            <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>        
            <td>80</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the question is clear about alignment using tools, not about the way how to edit all my codes. So please kindly remove your answer.

Comment: If you read my complete answer, I explain why you will not find the "tool" you are looking for, IT DOES NOT EXIST!

Comment: @Mr.Rick your question has nothing to do with the "javascript php html css"; your question is about using software to achieve your goal. Relevance to the question is?

Comment: @Mr.Rick I will not remove my answer, my answer stands to be true unless someone can prove otherwise. To My Knowledge what you are asking for does not exist, because of "HOW" I repeat "HOW" you want to align it! Your best option is to write a simple program to do it for you.

Comment: I need one click alignment for my codes which is clear in my question, if you don't know then why you answer about different things like manual editing or "industry standards". Maybe what i want is not "industry standard" or I will find it hardly, that's why i questioned here to solve my problem. So please remove the answer.

Comment: You asked a question, he answered it. There is not a tool to do this because no one ever wants to do it - if I was working with someone on code that was like this, I'd be frustrated. He does not need to remove his answer, even if it was off base. And seriously, Fred is right about the tags too. I'd doesn't really have any bearing on what you are trying to accomplish. Those language tags are for questions regarding the actual use of the language - not how it relates to formatting.